# How to run docker to process host file

Tags: docker, awk

For example, my image is based off apline, and I want to use awk to process a file on the host filesystem.

`docker run -ti alpine  awk ' { print "{\"index\":{}}"; }{print ;}' dump.json`

the error is `wk: dump.json: No such file or directory`
Because the file is not inside the container, and I only want to use alpine as a toolbox, I do not want to mount the file.

Answer (score 1):

stdin functions like a normal process for a `docker run` command that uses `-i`. Then stdout can be used as normal from the docker command.

```
cat dump.json \
  | docker run -i alpine awk ' { print "{\"index\":{}}"; }{print ;}' \
  | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Your container is isolated from the host.

You can copy from the host the file inside the container using

`docker cp`

see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

and then you have this file inside the container, so you can process awk on it